# Tab Outside Tab Control In Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

My Access 2007 form has a two buttons below a tab control (with a subform on each page).

With a tab-page or button focused, I can "tab" into the subform on that page (putting focus on the first control).  However, once a control in the subform has focus, I cannot "tab" out of the subform.  The focus iterates through the subform controls (not the entire form).

Is there a way to change this behavior?  When the last subform control has focus and the user pushes the tab key, I want the focus to be on the first button.

Comment: Ctrl-Tab should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the last subform control add an `[Event Procedure]` to the KeyDown event for the control:

```
Private Sub TheSubformControl_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyTab And Shift = 0 Then Me.Parent.ButtonToFocus.SetFocus
End Sub
```